# Good guide on VIM Scripting?

Tags: vim, scripting

I've used VIM for 10+ years, but never really into VIM scripting (always subjectively beliving that this was one area where VIM was weaker than Emacs).

Recently, the realization "in a VIM script, I can execute normal mode commands" made my mind go "a-ha" and suddenly start realizing why parts of VIM script is the way it is.

```
normal ma10jd'a20kp
```

is much more elegant than

```
Marker m = currentLocation();
advanceLines(10);
Buffer b = delete(currentLocation(), m);
advanceLines(-20);
insertBuffer(b);
```

Now question is -- what's a good resource to learn vim scripting from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The best advice I can give is that you read:

```
:help usr_41.txt
```

which will give you a good overview of the basics.  Then find some things that you want to do and create functions for them.  While you're doing this, make heavy use of:

```
:help function-list
```

to get an idea of what all the built in functions are.  Most of it is fairly similar to other scripting languages (albeit a harsher syntax), so any experience you have of text manipulation in python or whatever will be useful.

Also, look on the [vim scripts page](http://www.vim.org/scripts) and [Google](http://www.google.co.uk) to get examples of existing scripts to help expand your knowledge.

Finally (and probably most importantly), don't be afraid to ask on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) or the [Vim mailing list](http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim) and there'll be plenty of support for any problems you may have.

Answer (score 38):

Learn Vimscript the Hard Way is worth checking out too.

http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/

Comment: I found this book to be the best resource ever for learning Vimscript decently! :)

Answer (score 16):

I'm in a similar situation. It's still on my "to read" list, but I just found [Scripting the Vim editor](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/l-vim-script-1/) today. The articles from IBM's DeveloperWorks are usually very good, so probably worth checking out.

Comment: I did a bit of vimscript today and the IBM DevWorks guide was great, but I started with Part 1. (The answer links to Part 3.) http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-1/index.html

Comment: Many thanks for that article, @RichardMichael - that's precisely the sort of reading material I've been looking for all day!

Answer (score 16):

Al gave you a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153892/good-guide-on-vim-scripting/2154360#2154360). I'd also add [vim.wikia](https://vim.fandom.com) that has a few tips related to your question.

On a side note.

I wouldn't say that `ma10jd'a20kp` is more elegant. I see the following problems:

- it's quite difficult to maintain (what if the number of lines shall become a parameter?),
- people like to override keys they never learned to use (this could be fixed with a banged `:normal!`),
- some normal-mode commands have strange behaviour on side-case (like `<esc>` when the cursor is on the first column),
- it messes the mark **a**, and the unnamed register -- other scripts, or even the user may expect their values to not be altered by your script.

Comment: +1: I misread the original post as "is less elegant than" as I thought it clearly was!  Otherwise I would have commented on the unmaintainable `:normal` line.  I tend to use `:normal` only when I can't find a good way to do it with scripting constructs.  Either enter the keys one at a time manually or write a proper function that can be maintained.

Comment: vim.wikia link broken.

Comment: Thanks @jinbeomhong. _Wikia_ has become _fandom_. I've updated the link.